# Implementation of Esri ArcGIS Plugin Data Source using Monogdb

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, mongodb

I worked with plugin data source using file data and it worked fine [as given here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//000100000294000000). For MongoDB I downloaded the code given in GitHub and compiled it and registered it with categories.

How can I use this in ArcMap like will I get a new connection option in `Add new database connection`? I do not know how I will implement this.

For Simple file I used Java code and deployed the jar file to  ArcGIS by placing the JAR file in the `<ArcGIS Install Dir>\java\lib\ext` folder and when I opened ArcCatalog I saw the custom file as a feature class.

For Mongo I used the .Net code but I do not know after registering the dll with categories page how it can be accessed in ArcMap. i.e. How i can connect to MongoDB in ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 1):

You need implement interface IPlugInCreateWorkspace in class MongoDBWorkspacePluginFactory .
Here you can see a sample https://github.com/nicogis/MongoDBPlugIn/blob/98484f8738ad697f97a5ed7a63a924342308a072/MongoDBPlugIn/MongoDBWorkspacePluginFactory.cs#L48